# printing the answer, the "should be" and the desired answer in one line [Scheme (Beginning Student Language)]

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I am currently solving Ex. 3.3.1 where:

> Exercise 3.3.1.   The United States uses the English system of
>   (length) measurements. The rest of the world uses the metric system.
>   So, people who travel abroad and companies that trade with foreign
>   partners often need to convert English measurements to metric ones and
>   vice versa.
>
> Here is a table that shows the six major units of length measurements
>   of the English system:12
>
> English                   metric 1 inch               =   2.54    cm 1 foot   =   12  in. 1
>   yard  =   3   ft. 1 rod   =   5(1/2)  yd. 1 furlong   =   40  rd. 1 mile  =   8   fl.
>   Develop the functions inches->cm, feet->inches, yards->feet,
>   rods->yards, furlongs->rods, and miles->furlongs.
>
> Then develop the functions feet->cm, yards->cm, rods->inches, and
>   miles->feet.
>
> Hint: Reuse functions as much as possible. Use variable definitions to
>   specify constants.

```
;; Contract: inches->cm

;; Purpose: to convert inches to centimeters

;; Examples: (inches->cm 22/7) should be 7.9828514

;; Definition: [refines the header]
(define (inches->cm in)
  (* in 2.54))

;; Tests
(inches->cm 22/7) "should be" 7.98287514
```

When I ran the program, it ran like this:

```
7.98285714
"should be"
7.98285714
```

A possible flaw that I've been contemplating about is if my code has multiple functions with multiple design recipes, it would be harder for me to read if my program ran like this:

```
7.98285714
"should be"
7.98285714
-11.9928
"should be"
-11.9928
9.4247736
"should be"
9.4247736
```

It would cost me time to just figure out which is which. Is there a way to make the program run like the code below?

```
7.98285714 "should be" 7.98285714

-11.9928 "should be" -11.9928

9.4247736 "should be" 9.4247736
```

I'm still new in this "Functional Programming" paradigm and programming language and I don't know if there's something like a `printf()` and/or a `\n` like in C. But please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is that the results are being printed in separate lines, try this - it works in the Beginning Student Language:

```
(define (print actual expected)
  (string-append
   (number->string (exact->inexact actual))
   " should be "
   (number->string (exact->inexact expected))))

(print (inches->cm 22/7) 7.98287514)
=> "3.142857142857143 should be 7.98287514"
```

If you weren't restricted to the Beginner's language, this would be a much simpler alternative in Racket:

```
(printf "~a should be ~a~n" (inches->cm 22/7) 7.98287514)
```

Or even better, use [`check-expect`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/test-engine/index.html?q=) or some other unit testing framework, there are tools better suited for this job. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: I received an error: `printf: this function is not defined`

Comment: Mmmm, right. You're using beginner's language. Let me rephrase that answer

Comment: `check-expect` doesn't print `7.98285714 "should be" 7.98285714`, it only prints `The test passed`.

Comment: @exilyte it shouldn't matter what it _prints_, it's a framework for unit testing. There's no need to reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: Reply to your first comment: Thanks! That will help me test my programs without getting confused of which results are for which. Reply to your second comment: "There's no need to reinvent the wheel ;)". Thanks for the reminder, I read that in ~esr's how to become a hacker.